# How to write a WHERE statement in SQL that uses an integer column as a date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have to write a SQL request to pull some data from a server I have access to. The server uses postgresql.

There are columns in the data that look like `20150102`. Problem is, these column are integers (not strings) and thus seems not to be recognized as a date.

However, I need to pull observations where the date that is stored in `col1` is before the date that is stored in `col2` (plus x days).

So I was thinking about:

```
WHERE 
    TO_DATE(col1, 'YYYYMMDD') < (TO_DATE(col2, 'YYYYMMDD') + 10 days)
```

How can I do that? What is the correct syntax here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast *integer values* to *text* 1st:

```
WITH t(id,col1,col2) AS ( VALUES
  (1,20150102,20150103),
  (2,20150102,20150103),
  (3,20150102,20150102),
  (4,20150102,20150110)
)
SELECT * FROM t WHERE
to_date(col1::TEXT,'YYYYMMDD') < to_date(col2::TEXT,'YYYYMMDD' + interval '10 day');
```

Comment: actually just a question: how can I specify the + 10 days I needed to do?

Comment: updated @Noobie - `interval '10 day'`; all the docs regarding this are http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: If you can, I recommend you create a view that provides real date columns so you don't need to put that stuff in all your queries. Better yet, fix the table itself: ALTER table ALTER col1 TYPE date USING to_date(...). Storing dates as ints is just silly.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot modify the tables, only write requests. @Dmitry, I actually get an error message "source string too short for MM". It might be the case that some rows contain missing or wrongly coded data. Is it possible to get a NULL value when there is a problem instead of crashing my request?

Comment: is there something similar to `TRY_CONVERT`?